# How can I change the final position of a threaded-in faucet?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I installed a wall faucet and it got into the wrong direction because I had to tighten it well.

How I can make it point in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: Add a short extension pipe behind the faucet.  That will provide additional joints.  Small adjustments at each joint can yield the total rotation needed without going overboard or underboard on tightness.  If the faucet is aimed 90 degrees off, as the picture seems to indicate, add a 90 degree adapter where the hose connects.

Comment: As others have stated, take back apart, add a short brass nipple, and reinstall. A brass nipple will give a lot since brass is a soft metal with a certain amount of give. Stop when you get it turned into the position you want. You could also replace the valve with one  that has a backing flange to help hide the  broken wall finish

Answer (score 4):

Unscrew it and apply a bit more (or less) thread tape. Or use thread compound, which is a bit more forgiving of tightness.

Comment: I agree the tapered threads will seal way before bottoming out, count how many turns to remove. Retape or dope then install with 1 less turn.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to add a [SharkBite coupling](http://www.sharkbite.com/product/couplings/) before the threaded pipe end: Those couplings can rotate freely while connected and under pressure.  (Consequently, you'll then need to anchor the hose bib.)

Much harder, but old-fashioned "right" way: Mark how much rotation is needed to get it straight.  Unthread hose bib, heat supply line thread nipple until you can twist it, twist it exactly the right amount, then allow to cool before screwing hose bib back in.

Answer (score 0):

Unscrew it and note where you came off and try to get it to thread on sooner.

or add a spacer coupling that you can manipulate a bit to give you a bit of play.

No simple answers - trial and error. You might need more thread tape.